# How to check if the input value is coming from a select option or an input text

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-8, laravel-9

I wonder, how can I check that an input value is coming from a `select` option or an input with type of `text`.

For example, I have `select` option like this:

```
<select name="attr">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Then in the Controller, I can get the value by saying:

```
$request->attr
```

Now I need to know that the returned value of `$request->attr` is coming from a select option or an input with a type of `text`.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Why? Why does it matter?

Comment: @brombeer Yes I'm building a dynamic form handler and I really need to know for future stuff

Comment: but you don't have input type text

Comment: @Ainz In my form I have several inputs including type of `text` and bunch of `select` options. I need to find a way for knowing the value is coming from input with type of text or a select option

Comment: You can't. Info about which form field sent a value is not being sent with the form. If you really need to know you could use a "unique" `name` attribute, i.e. `name="text_attribute"` vs. `name="select_attribute"`

Comment: @brombeer I can't do that, because name of each input is generated dynamically and I don't know that this name is for a select option or input text

Comment: Then why not modify your dynamic input name generator to match what @brombeer said and generate the two names accordingly? Then in your controller, you'd make two if-statements to perform the different logic you need.

Comment: Then you probably need to keep track of the names and types your form builder created and get the info from there.

Comment: You should use javascript/ajax to change it live without refreshing your pages

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden input in your form to fill its value by javascript. set its value as **select** or **text** or **both** when user interacts with the related fields. After submission, PHP will also post this hidden input's value so you'll know its source.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do, is give the inputs and all dynamic form components an prefix. In your code just check what the prefix is so you can do whatever you want.